# Отображение другой директории htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

У меня есть код проекта, расположенный в директории `/folder/projectname`. Как средствами htaccess сделать доступ к проекту по адресу `/projectname` без переноса файлов и переадресаций?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(projectname/.*) /folder/$1
```

Comment: Данный вариант лишь переадресовывает на другой адрес, со сменой всех ссылок.

Comment: @АртурБойков  я понял, что  именно это и надо

Answer (score 1):

примерно так:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/projectname
rewriterule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [qsa,l]
```

это содержимое файла `.htaccess`, находящегося в *docroot*-е сайта.
его интерпретация должна быть разрешена в конфигурации сервера для соответствующего каталога (см. [документацию по allowoverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)).